# Volterra equation of the 2nd kind

Tags: integration

Since one of the limits of the integral is variable and is an out-of-integral term containing the desired function, we obtain an inhomogeneous Volterra equation of the 2nd kind.

$\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\rho)=\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\rho)+\int_{\rho}^{b_{end}}\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(s)\cdot\dfrac{s\cdot(a^2-\kappa\cdot\rho^2)}{\rho^2\cdot(a^2+\kappa\cdot s^2)}\,ds;$

For ease of integration, we introduce a new variable:

$\eta=\ln(1+\kappa\cdot(\dfrac{\rho}{a})^2);$

$e^{\eta}=(1+\kappa\cdot(\dfrac{\rho}{a})^2);$

$\rho^2=\dfrac{a^2\cdot(e^\eta-1)}{\kappa};$

We substitute it into our equation and reduce similar terms and factors:

$\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\rho(\eta))=\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\rho(\eta))+\int_{\rho(\eta)}^{b_{end}}\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(s)\cdot\dfrac{s\cdot(a^2-\kappa\cdot\dfrac{a^2\cdot(e^\eta-1)}{\kappa})}{\dfrac{a^2\cdot(e^\eta-1)}{\kappa}\cdot(a^2+\kappa\cdot s^2)}\,ds;$

$\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\rho(\eta))=\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\rho(\eta))+\int_{\rho(\eta)}^{b_{end}}\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(s)\cdot\dfrac{(2-e^{\eta})\cdot\kappa\cdot s}{(e^{\eta}-1)\cdot(a^2+\kappa\cdot s^2)}\,ds;$

$\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\rho(\eta))=\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\rho(\eta))+\dfrac{(2-e^{\eta})\cdot\kappa}{e^{\eta}-1}\cdot\int_{\rho(\eta)}^{b_{end}}\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(s)\cdot\dfrac{s}{a^2+\kappa\cdot s^2}\,ds;$

We change the integration variable, cancel similar terms and factors:

$s^2=\dfrac{a^2\cdot(e^{\eta_{s}}-1)}{\kappa};$

$\eta_{s}=\ln(1+\kappa\cdot(\frac{s}{a})^2);$

$d\eta_{s}=\dfrac{2\cdot\kappa\cdot s}{a^2\cdot(1+\kappa\cdot(\frac{s}{a})^2)}\,ds;$

$ds=\dfrac{a^2+\kappa\cdot s^2}{2\cdot\kappa\cdot s}\,d\eta;$

$\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\eta)=\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\eta)+\dfrac{(2-e^{\eta})\cdot\kappa}{e^{\eta}-1}\cdot\int_{\eta(\rho(\eta))}^{\eta(b_{end})}\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\eta_{s})\cdot\dfrac{s}{a^2+\kappa s^2}\cdot\dfrac{a^2+\kappa\cdot s^2}{2\cdot\kappa\cdot s}\,ds;$

$\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\eta)=\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\eta)+\dfrac{2-e^{\eta}}{2\cdot(e^{\eta}-1)}\cdot\int_{\eta}^{\eta(b_{end})}\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\eta_{s})\,d\eta_{s};$

We replace the integral with a function and substitute it into the previous equation:

$f(\eta)=\int_{\eta}^{\eta(b_{end})}\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\eta_{s})\,d\eta_{s};$

$\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\eta)=\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\eta)+\dfrac{2-e^{\eta}}{2\cdot(e^{\eta}-1)}\cdot f(\eta);$

We take the derivative with respect to the lower limit of the integral:

$f(\eta)^{'}_{\eta}=-\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\eta);$

We reduce the integral equation to a first-order inhomogeneous DE:

$f(\eta)^{'}_{\eta}=-(\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\eta)+\dfrac{e^{\eta}-2}{2\cdot(e^{\eta}-1)}\cdot f(\eta));$

We solve the corresponding homogeneous equation and reduce it to a form with separated variables:

$\dfrac{df(\eta)}{f(\eta)}=-\dfrac{e^{\eta}-2}{2\cdot(e^{\eta}-1)}\,d\eta;$

Auxiliary calculations of the right-hand side integral:

$\int\dfrac{e^{\eta}-2}{e^{\eta}-1}\,d\eta=\int(1-\dfrac{1}{e^\eta-1})\,d\eta=\eta-\int\dfrac{e^\eta d\eta}{e^\eta\cdot(e^\eta-1)}=\eta-\int\dfrac{de^\eta}{e^{2\cdot\eta}-e^\eta}=$

$=\eta-\int\dfrac{de^\eta}{e^{2\cdot\eta}-2\cdot e^\eta\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}}=\eta-\int\dfrac{de^\eta}{(e^{\eta}-\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}}=\eta-\frac{1}{2\cdot\frac{1}{2}}\cdot\ln|\dfrac{e^\eta-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}}{e^\eta-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}|=$

$=\eta+\ln|\dfrac{e^\eta}{e^\eta-1}|+C1;$

$\ln|f(\eta)|=-\frac{1}{2}\cdot(\eta+\ln|\dfrac{e^\eta}{e^\eta-1}|)+C2;$

We obtain a solution for the homogeneous equation:

$f(\eta)=(\dfrac{e^{2\cdot\eta}}{e^\eta-1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot C3;$

Now we find a solution to the inhomogeneous differential equation and represent $C3$ as a function of $\eta$:

$f(\eta)=(\dfrac{e^{2\cdot\eta}}{e^\eta-1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot C3(\eta);$

We take the derivative of the function with respect to $\eta$:

$f(\eta)^{'}_{\eta}=-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{2\cdot e^{2\cdot\eta}\cdot(e^\eta-1)-e^{\eta}\cdot e^{2\cdot\eta}}{(e^\eta-1)^2}\cdot(\dfrac{e^{2\cdot\eta}}{e^\eta-1})^{-\frac{3}{2}}\cdot C3(\eta)+(\dfrac{e^{2\cdot\eta}}{e^\eta-1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot C3(\eta)^{'}_{\eta}=$

$=(\dfrac{e^{2\cdot\eta}}{e^\eta-1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot C3(\eta)^{'}_{\eta}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{(e^{3\cdot\eta}-2\cdot e^{2\cdot\eta})\cdot e^{-3\cdot\eta}}{(e^\eta-1)^2\cdot(e^\eta-1)^{-\frac{3}{2}}}\cdot C3(\eta)=$

$=(\dfrac{e^{2\cdot\eta}}{e^\eta-1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot C3(\eta)^{'}_{\eta}-\dfrac{e^{-\eta}\cdot(e^\eta-2)}{2\cdot(e^\eta-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\cdot C3(\eta);$

We substitute into the original remote control, reduce similar factors and terms:

$(\dfrac{e^{2\cdot\eta}}{e^\eta-1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot C3(\eta)^{'}_{\eta}-\dfrac{e^{-\eta}\cdot(e^\eta-2)}{2\cdot(e^\eta-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\cdot C3(\eta)=-\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\eta)-\dfrac{e^{\eta}-2}{2\cdot(e^{\eta}-1)}\cdot(\dfrac{e^{2\cdot\eta}}{e^\eta-1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot C3(\eta);$

We reduce the differential equation to a form with separated variables and solve it:

$\dfrac{\sqrt{e^\eta-1}}{e^\eta}\cdot\dfrac{dC3(\eta)}{C3(\eta)}=-\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\eta)\,d\eta;$

$dC3(\eta)=-\dfrac{e^\eta}{\sqrt{e^\eta-1}}\cdot\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\eta)\,d\eta;$

$C3(\eta)=-\int\dfrac{e^{\eta_s}}{\sqrt{e^{\eta_s}-1}}\cdot\sigma_{\phi_{end}}({\eta_s})\,d{\eta_s}+C4;$

$C3(\eta)$ substitute into the required function:

$f(\eta)=(\dfrac{e^{2\cdot\eta}}{e^\eta-1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot(-\int\dfrac{e^{\eta_s}}{\sqrt{e^{\eta_s}-1}}\cdot\sigma_{\phi_{end}}({\eta_s})\,d{\eta_s}+C4);$

We solve the Cauchy problem: the limits of the integral coincide at $\eta=\eta(b_{end})$ - the function we introduced becomes equal to 0:

$0=(\dfrac{e^{2\cdot\eta(b_{end})}}{e^{\eta(b_{end})}-1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot(-\int^{\eta(b_{end})}\dfrac{e^{\eta_s}}{\sqrt{e^{\eta_s}-1}}\cdot\sigma_{\phi_{end}}({\eta_s})\,d{\eta_s}+C4);$

We express the constant $C4$, substitute it into the desired function, and it into the original integral equation and express the unknown function:

$\sigma_{\phi_{begin}}(\eta)=\sigma_{\phi_{end}}(\eta)+\dfrac{e^{\eta}-2}{2\cdot e^{\eta}\cdot\sqrt{e^{\eta}-1}}\cdot(-\int\dfrac{e^{\eta_s}}{\sqrt{e^{\eta_s}-1}}\cdot\sigma_{\phi_{end}}({\eta_s})\,d{\eta_s}+$

$+\int^{\eta(b_{end})}\dfrac{e^{\eta_s}}{\sqrt{e^{\eta_s}-1}}\cdot\sigma_{\phi_{end}}({\eta_s})\,d{\eta_s}).$

I got 2 integrals in my answer. How can they determine their limits? Since the answer in this form is clearly not correct.